# element disappears when appended to other element

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.image').forEach(el => {
 el.querySelector('span').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const clickedElement = e.target;
   document.querySelector('.append').append(clickedElement);
 });
});
```

```css
.image {
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.append {
 margin-top: 20px;
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span>image1</span>
</div>
<div class="image">
 <span>image2</span>
</div>

<div class="append"></div>
```

So I am trying to figure it out why when I click `image1 or image2` text in red background it appends to yellow background but it disappears from red background? How to stop it from disappearing from red background?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the element to make a copy using [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
const clickedElement = e.target.cloneNode(true);
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.image').forEach(el => {
 el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const clickedElement = e.target.cloneNode(true);
   document.querySelector('.append').append(clickedElement);
 });
});
```

```css
.image {
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.append {
 margin-top: 20px;
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span>image1</span>
</div>
<div class="image">
 <span>image2</span>
</div>

<div class="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` is moving the node itself-- [`.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) (passed `true` to clone the subtree as well) will create a copy you can append while leaving the original in place in the DOM:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.image').forEach(el => {
 el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const clickedElement = e.target;
   const clonedElement = clickedElement.cloneNode(true);
   document.querySelector('.append').append(clonedElement);
 });
});
```

```css
.image {
 background: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.append {
 margin-top: 20px;
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span>image1</span>
</div>
<div class="image">
 <span>image2</span>
</div>

<div class="append"></div>
```